# Method, function, this in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript code.

```
<script>
   var myobj = {
      fname : "abc",
      lname: "xyz",
      getvalue : function(v)
      {
        alert(typeof this.getvalue);
        alert( this.fname + " " + this.lname + " " + this.v );
      }

   }; 
   myobj.getvalue(3);  
</script>
```

As per my understanding, `getvalue` in the above code is method not function then how come `typeof this.getvalue` return function.

Why is the second alert in the above code shows `undefined` when point `v` as this.v ?

Comment: What do you think a `method` is?

Comment: a method is something that have no independent existance and are called using the instance of an object.

Comment: @sum1 in JavaScript that's just not true. There's no such distinction; every function is a function .

Comment: @Pointy do you mean there is no method in js ?

Comment: You can call it a method, but it still is just a plain old function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: By the way I am currently reading this book Javascript:the good parts.And there is this line `When a function is stored as a property of an object, we call it a method`. This is what confused me.

Comment: @sum1—yes, functions called via an object property (as in `myobj.getvalue()`) are called "methods", the language specification defines them that way: [*EMCA-262 §4.3.27*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.27). However, such functions are still first class objects and can be passed by reference and called from other contexts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As per my understanding, `getvalue` in the above code is method not function then how come `typeof this.getvalue` return function.

JavaScript doesn't have a concept of "methods" (not yet at least*). This is just a term colloquially used to describe *functions* that are assigned to properties of objects. Btw, [`typeof` if basically a lookup table](https://es5.github.io/#x11.4.3).

> Why is the second `alert` in the above code shows `undefined` when point `v` as `this.v` ?

Because `myobj` doesn't have a property `v`. Accessing a non-existing property returns `undefined`.

---

*: ECMAScript 6 (the next version of "JavaScript") [does have the concept of methods](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-method-definitions), but it's mostly syntactical and they are still just functions.

Comment: Wow completely satisfactory answer. Thanks !

Comment: One more thing, if js has no method then what shoul we call `toString()`.

Comment: ES5 does have the concept of a [*method*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.27) though, even if it's not as fully developed as in ES6 (draft). @sum1—call it a method. *typeof* has limited practical functionality.

Answer (score 2):

`v` is method parameter not a self object `ref` so you should only `v`

```
<script>
   var myobj = {
      fname : "abc",
      lname: "xyz",
      getvalue : function(v)
      {
        alert(typeof this.getvalue);
        alert( this.fname + " " + this.lname + " " + v );
      }

   }; 
   myobj.getvalue(3);  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not call the `getvalue` function with the `v` parameter, insted you just call `this.v`.
This might be the problem.